# Gitlab CI, ssh runner

Tags: ssh, gitlab, gitlab-ci

When I try to create ssh runner in deploy console I have this error:

```
Running with gitlab-ci-multi-runner 1.7.1 (f896af7)
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory
Will be retried in 3s ...
Using SSH executor...
ERROR: Preparation failed: open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory
Will be retried in 3s ...
ERROR: Build failed (system failure): open ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub: no such file or directory
```

On my server I created ssh key, and this key is in directory ~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub.
My .gitlab-ci.yml file:

```
stages:
- deploy
before_script:
    - whoami
mate-finder:
  stage: deploy
  script:
    - sudo apt-get update -qy
    - sudo apt-get install -y nodejs
    - sudo npm install
    - sudo ng build
    - sudo ng serve
```

How can I deploy my application on server? How must I configure my runner on the server, when I want to deploy my angular2 application on it?

Comment: I saw you did a 'whoami' there. My firs thought is that the home directories are not lining up.

Comment: @louahola when i move id_rsa.pub to another directory, problem was not solved.

Comment: https://gitlab.com/gitlab-org/gitlab-ci-multi-runner/issues/202; I would give that a shot

Answer (score 2):

You need to check, where config.toml is placed. You can do it with a search.

`find / -name 'config.toml'`

If result would be

`/etc/gitlab-runner/config.toml`

You running runner as `root`. And you need to specify full path like `/root/.ssh/id_rsa`.

If no - you running it under other user and you'll need to specify directory like `/home/user/.ssh/id_rsa`.

To find out which user you are - register `shell` executor and run `pwd` or `whoami`

---

I believe it would be `gitlab-runner` if not `root`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I change `~/.ssh/id_rsa` path to `/root/id_rsa`.

when I changed in `config.toml` it is not helped, but reconfigure the runner fix that.